# How check id of channel that message was sent in?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I check id of channel that message was sent in?

I try:

```js
message.channel.id.cache.get('channel id')
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `message.channel.id`? Returns the channel id based on the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the following (as pointed out by Sean in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181966/how-check-id-of-channel-that-message-was-sent-in#comment111727868_63181966)):

```js
message.channel.id
```

## References

- [`Discord.Message()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)
- [`TextChannel.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=id)